# Oracle connect by with nested subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, select, connect-by

I've 2 tables. 1st contains a reference to 2nd table, whereas 2nd table is self referencing.
Below is the sample tables

```
Table_P
-----------------------------
P_ID     P_TOKEN     FID
-----------------------------
1        P1          F1
2        P2          F2
3        P3          F3
4        P4          F4
-----------------------------
```

and

```
Table_F
----------------------------------
F_ID     F_TOKEN     PARENT_TOKEN
----------------------------------
1        F1          F2
2        F2          F3
3        F3          null
4        F4          null
----------------------------------
```

Result Expected

```
---------------------
P_TOKEN     F_TOKEN  
---------------------
F1          F3
F2          F3       
F3          F3       
F4          F4       
---------------------
```

Select Query

```
SELECT p.P_TOKEN,
  (select F_TOKEN from 
      (select tF.F_TOKEN, tF.PARENT_F from TABLE_F tF 
        connect by tF.F_TOKEN = prior tF.PARENT_TOKEN start with tP.FID = tF.F_ID)
    where PARENT_F is null
  ) as "F Value" FROM TABLE_P tF
```

But doing so throws an exception

```
ORA-00904: "tP"."FID": invalid identifier
```

Kindly suggest the work around. Many thanks.

Comment: Do you see "tP"."FID" in your query? I don't.

Comment: Well, there is a `tP.FID` in the query (line 4 column 66), but not quoted as `"tP"`; but if you run this it complains about `"P"."P_TOKEN"` first anyway as you don't have anything aliased as `p`. What is your complete actual query and corresponding error?.

Comment: Looking at the data, the column FID in table_P cannot be joined to F_ID from Table_F anyway (if your intent was to join the two tables which you're not doing), as one of them is a number and other is a VARCHAR2. In the result, why does the P_Token column have values such as F1, F2,... instead of P1, P2,... It would be good if you could please explain the logic behind the result as well, because as of now it seems you are just finding the final parent of an F_Token going up to the root and returning the same element if it is null. That could be done from just Table_F.

Answer (score 0):

Your current query doesn't seem to match up with the error message you reported or with your table schemas, you have datatype mismatches, and your connect-by doesn't seem to get the information you want anyway - it may get multiple rows for each parent row, for a start. There are issues with referring to table aliases more than one subquery down in some versions of Oracle as well.

It might be simpler to do a join. You can get the `TABLE_F` hierarchy information with something like:

```
select tF.F_TOKEN, tF.PARENT_TOKEN, connect_by_root F_TOKEN as ROOT_F_TOKEN,
  connect_by_isleaf as ISLEAF
from TABLE_F tF 
connect by tF.F_TOKEN = prior tF.PARENT_TOKEN;

F_TOKEN PARENT_TOKEN ROOT_F_TOKEN     ISLEAF
------- ------------ ------------ ----------
F1      F2           F1                    0 
F2      F3           F1                    0 
F3                   F1                    1 
F2      F3           F2                    0 
F3                   F2                    1 
F3                   F3                    1 
F4                   F4                    1
```

You're only interested in leaf nodes, and those will allow you to match the generated `ROOT_F_TOKEN` with the parent `FID`. Using that as an inline view:

```
select tP.P_TOKEN, tF.F_TOKEN
from TABLE_P tP
join (
  select tF.F_TOKEN, connect_by_root F_TOKEN as ROOT_F_TOKEN,
    connect_by_isleaf as ISLEAF
  from TABLE_F tF 
  connect by tF.F_TOKEN = prior tF.PARENT_TOKEN
) tF on tF.ROOT_F_TOKEN = tP.FID
where tF.ISLEAF = 1;

P_TOKEN F_TOKEN
------- -------
P1      F3      
P2      F3      
P3      F3      
P4      F4
```